# Display categories and their counts

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database (Jobs and Categories), I need help with an SQL that will select the categories and also count the number of jobs in each category. I am using MySQL if that helps.

So far

```
SELECT * from categories c left join jobs j on (c.job_id = j.job_id);
```

Thanks

Comment: I mean your database *structure* - what the tables look like and what columns they have.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a CategoryName column...

```
select c.CategoryName,
       count(*)
from  Categories c
join  Jobs       j  on j.job_id = c.jobID
group by c.CategoryName
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table structure is similar to this:

**Category**
ID, Name

**Job**
ID, CategoryID, Name

```
SELECT Category.Name, COUNT(Job.ID)
FROM Job
    INNER JOIN Category ON Job.CategoryID = Category.ID
```

Comment: imho LEFT join is more appropriate here (you have to display also categories with 0 jobs)

Comment: I dont understand: Are u saying that it'd would be great if I use LEFT in case I want to display 0 jobs or what? What difference does INNER make, please? @BorisBucha

Comment: `INNER JOIN` will include only records that match in the joined table, while `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will return nulls for the records that do not match. Thanks to @Jeff Atwood, there is a great blog post with Venn diagrams on the joins. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: @Dustin great, got it now. You are awesome

Comment: @Don aMOEBa: Yes, Boris meant actually that. If you want to account for all the categories, including those with no jobs in them, you'll need to use LEFT JOIN like this: `... FROM categories LEFT JOIN jobs ON ...` (i.e. `categories` on the left side of the left join).